# Failed to run RabbitMQ from shell script

Tags: shell, rabbitmq

Use the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /rabbitmq_server-3.9.7/sbin

./rabbitmq-server -detached

./rabbitmqctl start_app
./rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin
./rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator
./rabbitmqctl add_vhost admin
./rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p admin admin "." "." ".*"
```

I tried to run RabbitMQ as a shell script but encountered the following error

```
[root@root data]# sh xxx.sh 
Starting node rabbit@root...
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@root'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@mgh
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@root]

rabbit@root:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on root
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on root
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-809-rabbit@root'
 * effective user's home directory: /root
 * Erlang cookie hash: b2VvOfpVFsHp7dNeBq1SBg==

Fri Dec 17 02:14:44 PST 2021
Fri Dec 17 02:14:49 PST 2021
Error: this command requires the 'rabbit' app to be running on the target node. Start it with 'rabbitmqctl start_app'.
Arguments given:
        add_user admin admin

Usage

rabbitmqctl [--node <node>] [--longnames] [--quiet] add_user <username> <password>
Error: this command requires the 'rabbit' app to be running on the target node. Start it with 'rabbitmqctl start_app'.
Arguments given:
        set_user_tags admin administrator

Usage

rabbitmqctl [--node <node>] [--longnames] [--quiet] set_user_tags <username> <tag> [...]
Error: this command requires the 'rabbit' app to be running on the target node. Start it with 'rabbitmqctl start_app'.
Arguments given:
        add_vhost admin

Usage

rabbitmqctl [--node <node>] [--longnames] [--quiet] add_vhost <vhost> [--description <description> --tags "<tag1>,<tag2>,<...>"]
Error: this command requires the 'rabbit' app to be running on the target node. Start it with 'rabbitmqctl start_app'.
Arguments given:
        set_permissions -p admin admin . . .*

Usage

rabbitmqctl [--node <node>] [--longnames] [--quiet] set_permissions [--vhost <vhost>] <username> <conf> <write> <read>
```

If no shell script is used, the commands in the shell script can be executed without error .

I wonder what the reason is, is it the shell script?
Several virtual machines have been tested with this problem.

Comment: Does it help to put a `sleep 9` before doing the _start app_?

Comment: BTW, I took the liberty to remove the _bash_ tag, because there is no bash involved in your question.